# Randomly locating images in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

Basically, what I want to realise is a matching game like this :

[image: javascript matching game]

I got lost when I was trying to add 2 sets of images randomly and here is my code.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta author="qliuan" content="matching game">
    <title>Javascript Matching Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="set_the_game()" id="theBody">
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>Please click on the extra image on the left hand side</p>
    <hr width="1" size="500">
    <script src="matching_game.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var finished = false;
var total = 8;
var theBody = document.getElementById('theBody');

function set_the_game(){

while(!finished){

        for (var i = total; i > 0; i--) {
            var this_img = document.createElement('img');
            var relative_img = document.createElement('img');
            this_img.src = "smileyface.png";
            relative_img.src = "smileyface.png";

            // I wanna set the image using horizontal and vertical locations
            var x1 = Math.random()*501;
            var y1 = Math.random()*501;
            x1 = Math.floor(x1);
            y1 = Math.floor(y1);
            x2 = x1 + 500;
            y2 = y1;

            this_img.style.left = x1 + "px";
            this_img.style.top = y1 + "px";
            the_body.appendChild(this_img);

            relative_img.style.left = x2 + "px";
            relative_img.style.top = y2 + "px";
            the_body.appendChild(relative_img);
        }
    }
}
```

The image file is in the same directory as the code files, but the images are not loading.

I cannot find any information about this particular problem on Google, maybe because it's too easy, but I do need your help.

Comment: you never appear to set `finished` to ` true` so you have probably created an infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, but that is another story, I will remember to modify it, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

check your variable name its ***theBody*** and not ***the_body***

You have declared:

```
var theBody = document.getElementById('theBody');
```

and you have used:

```
the_body.appendChild(this_img);

the_body.appendChild(relative_img);
```

correct the name:

```
theBody.appendChild(this_img);

theBody.appendChild(relative_img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the images don't display in the correct location, I have revised your code to enable images to display. Here's the [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yewavvko/) Scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the images.

I didn't like how you were using the `onload` function to call the JavaScript function, so I got rid of the `set_the_game` function. I also removed your `while(!finished)` loop, because as far as I could tell, it was completely pointless and provided no purpose other than to (hopefully unintentionally) infinite loop.

As Arjun pointed out, you also referred to the variable `theBody` as `the_body` further down in your code, so I corrected that. Finally, here's the JavaScript code that displays images:

```
var total = 8;
var theBody = document.getElementById('theBody');

for (var i = total; i > 0; i--) {
    var this_img = document.createElement('img');
    var relative_img = document.createElement('img');
    this_img.src = "smileyface.png";
    relative_img.src = "smileyface.png";

    // I wanna set the image using horizontal and vertical locations
    var x1 = Math.random()*501;
    var y1 = Math.random()*501;
    x1 = Math.floor(x1);
    y1 = Math.floor(y1);
    x2 = x1 + 500;
    y2 = y1;

    this_img.style.left = x1 + "px";
    this_img.style.top = y1 + "px";
    theBody.appendChild(this_img);

    relative_img.style.left = x2 + "px";
    relative_img.style.top = y2 + "px";
    theBody.appendChild(relative_img);
}
```

Like I said, the images don't display in the correct location, so you'll have to fix that in your HTML (maybe also using CSS).